# -1 index in array?

Tags: python, arrays, indexing

I am trying to use:

```
num_new = num[i,-1]
```

to get the last segment of the array. However, it returns `[]` when `i = 0`, and `num = [3]`

Do I have to use like `num[i, len(num)]`? 
Is there any other attention need to pay when using `-1` to retrieve array elements?

Comment: can you prepare a proper example for the input data? Specifically, `lists` and `arrays` are two very different things in python, and it's important to show what you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is not a matter of -1, but python list slicing.

`some_list[-n]` means `n`th element of list from end of list, so you will get 5 as a result in following example:

```
some_list = [1, 3, 5]
last_elem = some_list[-1]  # 5
```

And this is not a core issue of your question.

List slicing in python works with this args:
`some_list[_start_:_end_:_step_]`
And *end* th element is **exclusive**.
So if you are trying to [3][0:-1], this excludes last element and returns empty list.

If you want to get last segment of list, you should slice like this:

```
some_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
sliced_list = some_list[3:]   # [4, 5]
neg_1_list = some_list[3:-1]  # [4]
```

[This](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) will help you.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I am a python beginner and my question might be a bit naive but I thought -1 refers to the last element instead of the one before last. Like for a string, s = "hello world", s[-1] = 'd', right?

Comment: @KenS -1 refers the last element. But in your case, -1st element is excluded by python list slicing. You can get last element using -1 in ordinary case like `some_list[-1]`, but this cuts last element in list slicing because _end_ th element is exclusive.